# Cakephp session undefined

Tags: session, cakephp

I have a simple project in cakephp (version) with 2 controller. In both I used session but just in one of them session work? My code from problem controller is:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Session');
    public function constructClasses() {
        $this->Session->check('language');
        $this->Session->read('language');
    }
}
```

Also I try with SessionHelper and without it but I received same error:

Call to a member function check() on a non-object

Comment: try calling it statically with `CakeSession::check('language');`

Comment: Check your error log for things like : `headers already sent` - The code snippet in the question does not help identify the cause.

Comment: I think is wrong to read or write session in a controller in cakephp. I moved my code in a function and code work.